# Android activity stack behaviors

Tags: android, stack, lifecycle

I see a lot of stuff here about the android stack, but I just can't get things to work the way I want them to. In the following diagram I've numbered each of the transitions.

[image: app navigation flowchar]

Transition 8 was easy. I just start the level difficulty choose activity using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY. Then, hitting back will just skip over it and go back to the level choose activity.

Transition 4 caused a problem because hitting back in the game after restarting ended up in the previous instance of the same game. I was calling finish(), so I don't know why it often stuck around, but using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY when starting the game activity solves this issue. However, this causes problems because transitions 6 and 7 don't work. Starting the app from the task manager or from the icon will always start at the main menu.

The biggest problem is transition 5. Hitting home leaves the app. There's no way to trap it so I can pop up a dialog to ask the user if they really wish to exit. So, that means I need to get transitions 6 and 7 to come back to the game activity. I don't know how to do that.

What I need to know is which flags to add to the various intents so that transition 4 doesn't keep multiple instances of game activity running while transitions 6 and 7 end up coming back to the game activity (assuming that's where they pressed the home button).